# Trouble with creating/sizing a dynamic array (pointer) in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-arrays

What this does should be quite obvious, but my userLetters array is incorrectly sized... Whats going on?? I thought to get the size of the array you multiply the size of the elements by the amount you want?

I need the userLetters array to be the same length as the length of the user string.

Note: user is a global variable set to getenv(USER)

```
// Get an integer array representing the userid string in values
fprintf(stdout, "user has length %d\n", strlen(user));
int * userLetters = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * strlen(user));
fprintf(stdout, "Created userLetters from username %s\n", user);
fprintf(stdout, "userLetters has length %d\n", sizeof(userLetters)/sizeof(int));
```

This is the output:

```
user has length 6
Created userLetters from username abcdef
userLetters has length 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sizeof(userLetters)
```

Gives you the `sizeof(pointer)` not `sizeof(array)`

While doing dynamic memory allocation you do

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

so `n` is the number of elements in the array.

Comment: I figured, how do I get the size of the array if its dynamically initialized?

Comment: @JayB There are twenty billion SO questions about that. Short answer: you have to store the size somewhere. A pointer is a pointer. It doesn't matter where it points to.

Comment: @JayB You need to keep track of number of elements in the array separately.

Comment: @JayB: You created it yourself, e.g., sizeof(int) * strlen(user). Btw what are you trying to achieve? userLetters is integer array each element taking probably four bytes, whereas user is char array? (each element taking 1 bytes)

Comment: @Gopi ok. so I'll just save use strlen(user) as the size. thanks.

Comment: @gio I'm creating an integer array of values that corresponds to the letters in the username. I want different values than the ascii equivalents, so I'm running the array through a function

Comment: @JayB You yourself know that number of elements in the array is `int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);` so n is the number of elements in the array what are you looking for?